# Getting Clojure to run (lein repl)

Tags: clojure

I'm just trying to get Clojure set up. Here is some code that I am trying to run in lein repl:

```
(def numbers (into [] (range 0 100)))
(sum numbers)
```

But I get this error:

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve
>   symbol: sum in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)

I don't know what this means. Is my installation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which `sum` function you're trying to call, but you can use `reduce`:

```
user=> (def numbers (into [] (range 0 100)))
#'user/numbers
user=> (reduce + numbers)
99
```

Comment: My bad. This code came from a book that I am following to learn the language. I didn't realize that `sum` wasn't a built in function, but one that they had defined as a way to introducing `reduce` and `fold`. Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: Why do you quote `+` in this answer? A bit of trivia: in this case `apply` can be used instead of `reduce` to get the same result (this is true of many other functions that take a variable argument count)

Comment: Whoops on the quote. Fixed.